# GUI error Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I've got a little problem with my saving file program.. When I run it there is an error which says that "Desktop localisation is unavaliable" Is there something wrong with my code or with laptop? 
Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import Tkinter as T,  tkFileDialog
import os
from time import gmtime, strftime
import serial

class Program(T.Frame):

    def __init__(self, root):

        T.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        T.Label(self, text = 'Better do that man').pack()
        T.Button(self, text='Save Me!', command=self.save).pack()


        self.fileop = options = {}
        options['filetypes'] = [('all files', '.*'), ('text files', '.txt'),('dat files','.dat')]
        options['initialfile'] = 'myfile.txt'
        options['parent'] = root
        options['initialdir'] = 'C:\Users\Michał\Desktop'

    def save(self):
        filename = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename(**self.fileop)
        root.destroy()

        if filename:
            file = open(filename, 'a')
            time = strftime("%A, %d %b %Y, %H:%M:%S ", gmtime())
            file.write(time)
            file.write('\n')
            entry = raw_input('Treść: \n')
            file.write(entry)
            file.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
    root = T.Tk()
    Program(root).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The code works for me without any errors. This is probably some issue with your python-configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this error means that you have no "Desktop" folder in the specific localized version of windows that you are using. It's not a python or tkinter error per se, it's just that your code is depending on an OS feature (a desktop folder) that isn't present.

You can probably work around this error by simply changing the initial directory to being the current directory.